# Create disclaimer screen where user has to scroll all the way down

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I need to create a discaimer screen with long text (which is localized to different languages).

The user should scroll down to the buttom of the text then see the "Agree" button.

Since Alerts are rather limited I created a UIViewController, and put a ScrollView into it.

Now I put a TextView into this Scrollview - but the problem is this TextView should not be scrollable on its own but should have the exact size it needs for the complete text that it holds (which is of course different for each langauge and always more than the screen height can hold without scrolling) and then under that long TextView I need to position the UIButton.

Both the TextView + Button are in the ScrollView.

Since the UITextView has different heights depending on the current language - how can I set up this complete screen correctly - ideally with IB. Or if not possible programmatically?

Or is there a totally different much easier way?

Comment: You shouldn't need an entire view controller dedicated to it. A UIAlertView should automatically create a scrollable text box with appropriate buttons!

Comment: but the buttons are visible even though the text has not been scrolled down to the buttom - I need to be sure that the user scrolled down the complete text!

Comment: oh, well in that case, it may be a little more tricky. You can put in the disclaimer in a few different popups and have them dismiss or agree in multiple contexts.

Comment: how much text are you talking about exactly?

Comment: @user387184 Don't use a `UITextView`. Use a `UILabel`. Add the label and the buttons to the scroll view. The trick is ensuring the label is sized to fully fit the text regardless of language and the buttons need to be positioned below the label.

Comment: Thanks for that trick. However, I just used a UILabel, put in the long text, set Word Wrap in UIB - but the label does not resize nor is there a word wrap. Is there another trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a UILabel (with number of lines set to 0) with the buttons below it to a scroll view. Set up the constraints so that the buttons have a vertical spacing constraint to the bottom of the label. Give the label a fixed width constraint and a height constraint. Make an IBOutlet to the height constraint, and adjust the constant parameter of that constraint in code using the value you get from sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:. You will also need to adjust the scroll view's contentSize using this same value plus what ever size you need to fit the buttons. This will cause the label to have the correct height based on the text it contains, and your buttons will always be a set distance below that label.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.label.text = @"dfkl;jfjdfkjf sdfl klf;jskdl;fja skfjdklfj skdlfjs dklfjsklfj sklfjskl;f jks;alfjsk;lfjs;klfj;kfjs;kljk;lfjskdfj;klf j;klf jkl;fj;klfj;klfj k;fs;klfjsk;lfj ;klfjk;alfjk;alfjk;lfjk;lfjlkf kl;ajf akl;sfj sk;fk;lfjsk;ldfjsk;lfjsk;lfjsklfjkl;s fjklsafj kslfjkl fjklasfjklajfklafjaksdlfj lsdkf jsklfskl;f skld fjlk;sfklsfj ksff;kjdsfj sfkl;fkl;fklklfjlk;";
    CGSize labelSize = [self.label.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, CGFLOAT_MAX)]; // 280 is the width of the label set in IB
    self.heightCon.constant = labelSize.height;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width, labelSize.height +120);

}
```

In this example heightCon is the IBOutlet to the height constraint of the label made in IB. I did this in viewDidLoad, but you would need to do this wherever you populate your label with the text.

Comment: Thank you very much - got the label to resize now, also the btn is positioned correctly - just the scroll view does not change its height - even though when debugging it prints the correct height. How can that be? I also reduced the priority of the scrolviews "bottom space to superview" to 1, but still it does not resize. Can you tell me please what else could cause this?

Comment: Check your constraints in case it does not work - this solution is perfect + understandable + clean IMHO. However compared to Android, I find it still ridiculous how much effort and how complicated it is in iOS for such a simple thing.

Comment: @user387184, are you changing the size of the scroll view itself, or its contentSize?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need an entire view controller dedicated to it. A UIAlertView should automatically create a scrollable text box with appropriate buttons!

A simple couple of lines below. Don't forget to set UIAlertViewDelegate in your header file:

```
NSString *message = @"This is a test message.\n\nYou should avoid this and that\n\nThis goes to the next line.";
NSString *title = @"Disclaimer";

[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self    cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil] show];
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the stated requirements of requiring the user to scroll through all of the message before being able to tap the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this is by creating a UITableViewController (call it DisclaimerViewController). First row displays the text.  Second row is an accept cell and third is a deny cell.

Create a protocol and delegate in the new UITableViewController. The protocol should have selectors for Accept and Deny.  The delegate should allow for any object that conforms to the new protocol.

From your Presenting ViewController, show the new DisclaimerViewController modal.  Make sure you set the delegate to self and implement the protocol.  Since the accept and deny cells are at the bottom of the UITableView, you know that the user scrolled to the bottom. There is no other way to get to the Accept and Deny cells for them to tap.

This seems like a lot of work, and it is.  But now, if there is anywhere else I need to have a disclaimer text, I can reuse this code with no code change.